# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Select)`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am having some problems with a react project, I am working with hooks and I am getting a problem witha method passed as a prop to the hook. I am using materail ui as well, this is my code:

```
import { Container, Grid, Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Store from '../component/store/store'

class StoreBuilder extends Component {
    state = {
        DivisionState: 'Store 1',
        DivisionData: [
            {
                id: 1,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 3'
            }
        ]
    };
    handleChangeDivision(event) {
        this.setState({ DivisionState: event.target.value });
    }

    renderDivisionOptions() {
        return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem
                    key={i}
                    value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
                    {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {     
        return (
            <div>
                <Container >
                    <Grid >
                    <Store stores={this.state.DivisionState} 
                            onChange={this.handleChangeDivision}
                            render ={this.renderDivisionOptions()}>

                    </Store>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default StoreBuilder;
```

The next is the hook code:

```
import { Container, Grid, Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const store = (props) => {

    return (

        <div>
            <Container >
                <Grid >
                    <Select value={props.DivisionState}
                        onChange={props.handleChangeDivision}
                    >
                        {() =>props.render()}
                    </Select>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );

}
export default store;
```

The issue is in the next code, I'm not pretty sure if it is possible to do the next code, I'm trying to pass the renderDivisionOptions method as a param to be used in the hook with the props:

```
 {() =>props.render()}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a function `{() =>props.render()}` to the `<Select>`, but it seems that you need to call the function instead:

```
<Select value={props.DivisionState}
    onChange={props.handleChangeDivision}
>
    {props.render()}
</Select>
```

In addition, if the `Select` element expects a ReactNode, you might need to wrap it with a fragment:

```
<>{props.render()}</>
```

Since you pass `renderDivisionOptions` as a callback to another component, it loses its context (`this`). You need to convert it to an arrow function, or bind it in the constructor.

```
renderDivisionOptions = () => {
    return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
        return (
            <MenuItem
                key={i}
                value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
                {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
            </MenuItem>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: I've used <>{props.render()}</> and I've changed in the main component by render ={this.renderDivisionOptions}, but I am getting the issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DivisionData' of undefined

Comment: You need to bind `renderDivisionOptions` to the instance. See update.